# readOGR cannot open layer error

Tags: r, leaflet, rgdal, ogr

I'm going through [Leaflet tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html) and I have stumbled upon file loading error which reads as follows:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv, : Cannot open data source
```

The code that leads to this:

```
library(rgdal)
countries <- readOGR("./json/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

I have saved `countries.geojson` file in in `json` directory and set working directory to the directory that contains `json` directory.

I've tried to load the file by downloading it from Github:

```
countries <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoboundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
```

and I got this error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = 
use_iconv, : Cannot open layer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try altering the layer name to the filename without the extension:

```
countries <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geoboundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson", layer = "countries")
```

For some reason in some environments the layer needs to be called "OGRGeoJSON", in other it needs to be called the filename without the extension.

For example with the latest R and rgdal versions on my OSX, it requires "OGRGeoJSON", but on our production machine running CentOS, it requires the filename. I suspect this is something to do with different versions of the underlying gdal C libraries.

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out the issue this has been the only solution that worked. Wish it was more commonly known as all the tutorials suggest using "OGRGeoJSON" for .geojson files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still unable to load the file. Tweaking the `layer` argument doesn't help.